# <c:if test='${not empty "${records}"}'> never evaluates false

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am having a problem with JSTL and empty operator. I already made few simple pages and everything worked fine, but now I have:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <html>
    <body>

     <form action="/Projekt/myaccount" method="post">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
                 <td>Artist</td>
                 <td>Record Name</td>
                 <td>Delete</td>
         </tr>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${records}">
         <tr>
                 <td>${item.artist}</td>
                 <td>${item.recordName}</td>
                 <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name='${item.recordName}|${item.recordName}'/>
                 </td>
         </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    <hr/>
        <input type="submit" name="back" value="back"/>
        <c:if test='${not empty "${records}"}'>
               <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete selected"/>
        </c:if>
     </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

now no matter if I set the records attribute or not, the delete button shows up:

```
<c:if test='${not empty "${records}"}'>
           <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete selected"/>
    </c:if>
```

in normal situation to records attribute I pass ArrayList and then use foreach, but sometimes ArrayList is empty, so in those situations I don't want delete button to show up, I fought that easiest way to achieve this would be to use this empty operator. Where am I making a mistake?

I even tried to manually set this attribute to null:

```
if (ar.size() != 0)
    request.setAttribute("records", ar);
else
    request.setAttribute("records",null);
```

EDIT:
@Qwe: yes you are right, it worked for me before because I tested if attribute was empty in my way, it was always true, because I used wrong construct, but it worked because I just wanted to show one string, if there was no String nothing showed up so I was thinking that everything worked fine.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`<c:if test='${not empty "${records}"}'>` as well as `<c:if test="${!empty '${showWarning}'}">` (from your comment) will **always** resolve to **true** because you're are actually testing if a String `${records}` is empty or not, and obviously it is not.

Just to be sure - by String `${records}` I mean a String value, just as if you were assigning it in Java like `String foo = "${records}";`.

The next line of code will test if `records` variable (that is looked up from page, request, session or application scope) is empty or not:

```
<c:if test="${not empty records}">
```

The line of code is 100% guaranteed to work :)

Also, `request.setAttribute("records",null)` is a bad way to remove attributes because `empty` tests not just request scope, but page, session etc. Use `<c:remove var='records'/>` instead.

Comment: If I try this piece of code, exception is raised:org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/userrecords.jsp (line: 26, column: 15) equal symbol expected. The funny thing is, that in other .jsp I use                                         <c:if test="${!empty '${showWarning}'}">
       <b>${showWarning}</b>
    </c:if>                                                           and it works fine (it shows when it should)

Comment: and what's in line 26? changing to doublequotes doesn't fix it?

Comment: In line 26 I have this if tag and empty operaotor, double quotes doesen't help, to be honest I don't fully grasp when I need single and when double quotes, but I observed that when I use those empty operators I must use double and single ones, as I said it works on other .jsp that I made.

Comment: answer edited, when you use empty operator you don't need any kind of qoutes

Comment: If what I wrote always resulted to true, why then: <c:if test="${!empty '${showWarning}'}"> <b>${showWarning}</b> </c:if> works for me in other files? As I said if I put <c:if test="${not empty records}"> in my code, I get exception. EDIT: Sorry It works now :D, but still why my method worked before, I am wondering.

Comment: it's superb and worked for me thanks a lot @OlegMikheev